# Javascript Comparison Loop Not Working Between an Integer and an Array of Integers

Tags: javascript, if-statement, integer, comparison

Based on the code I have below, the user_id_org should match with the first entry of the array in orgs. I had this working without issue but now cannot get it to work, am unsure what I changed, and can't find the issue. When I run the code below, it returns with `"No! We did not intersection with 1 of multiple orgs!"` when it should return with `"Yes! We matched with 1 of multiple orgs!"`. My goal here is to understand why/what I am doing wrong as to why the numbers are not matching, along with getting a fix.

Additionally, if someone has advice on how I could improve this code, I'd love to hear it.

```
var orgs = [1234,12345,37463,47716,37463];
var org_id = '';
var user_search = 1;
var org_search = 5;
var user_id_org = 1234;

if (org_id == '') {
    if (user_search == 1) { //User Known
        if (org_search == 1) {
                //Check the single org and see if the org ID is tied to the found user, if so attach user to the correct org.
                //If no intersection, submit a ticket as the user and do (information to be discussed in the meeting)
                var arrayLength = orgs.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    if (orgs[i] == user_id_org) {
                        var intersection = 'Yes! We matched with 1 org!'
                    } else {
                        var intersection = 'No! We did not intersection with 1 org!'
                    }
                }
                console.log(intersection)
        } else if (org_search > 1){
                //Loop through orgs and see if orgs any intersection the org ID tied to the found user, if so attach user to the correct org.
                var arrayLength = orgs.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                    if (orgs[i] == user_id_org) {
                        var intersection = 'Yes! We matched with 1 of multiple orgs!'
                    } else {
                        var intersection = 'No! We did not intersection with 1 of multiple orgs!'
                    }
                }
                console.log(intersection)
        } else if (org_search == 0) {
                //Create a ticket assigned to the user, and flag it (meeting)
                console.log('We did find a user, but no orgs at all, off to the dedicated org we go.')
        } else {
            console.log('Matching Error')
        }
    } else if (user_search !== 1) {
        if (org_search >= 1) {
            console.log('We did not find a user but found multiple orgs! To the dedicated org we go.')
        } else if (org_search == 1) {
            console.log('We did not find a user but found a single org! Assign them to the org.')
        } else if (org_search == 0) {
            var intersection = 'No intersection because we did not find a user.'

        } else {
            console.log('No User Found Error')
        }
        console.log(intersection)
    } else {
        console.log('Error');
    }
} else if (org_id !== '') {
    if (user_search == 1) {
        var intersection = 'We matched because we had an org ID and found a user.'
    } else if (user_search !== 1) {
        //Create user and attach them to the org_id.
        var intersection = 'We received an org ID but no user, go create them!'
    } else {
        console.log('Org ID Provided Error')
    }
    console.log(intersection)
} else {
    return 'Primary Org ID Sorting Error';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with these lines of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (orgs[i] == user_id_org) {
        var intersection = 'Yes! We matched with 1 of multiple orgs!'
    } else {
        var intersection = 'No! We did not intersection with 1 of multiple orgs!'
    }
}
```

The `for` loop continues from `0` to `arrayLength - 1`. On the 1st iteration (i.e. `i` is `0`), the `intersection` variable is set to `'Yes!...'`. On subsequent iterations, it is overwritten to `'No!...'`. You should exit early using the `break` statement (or `return` if there's no more code in the function that's relevant).

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (orgs[i] == user_id_org) {
        var intersection = 'Yes! We matched with 1 of multiple orgs!'
        break; // 'skip' the remaining iterations
    } else {
        var intersection = 'No! We did not intersection with 1 of multiple orgs!'
    }
}
// break jumps here
```

Other advice,

- learn to debug your using breakpoints or console.logs.
- use `===` instead of `==` which has unexpected type casting rules.
- use `let` and `const` instead of `var`
- end statements with semicolons `;`
- just styling, but most JS avoids using `{}` around one-line blocks
- prefer `array.forEach` to traditional `for` loops.